# mysql order by numeric column separating positive and negative values

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I want to list positive values of the weight column ordered by weight in ascending order, followed by negative values in whatever order.

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM `mytable`
WHERE weight >= 0
ORDER BY weight 
UNION
SELECT *
FROM `mytable`
WHERE weight < 0
ORDER BY weight
```

And I got:

`SQL Error (1221): Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a single query and then an appropriate `order by`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `mytable`
ORDER BY (weight >= 0) desc,
         weight;
```

MySQL treats booleans in a numeric context as a number, so the expression `(weight >= 0)` is treated as "1" (for positive) and "0" (for negative).

You cannot depend on the ordering of a `union` query, in any situation, because the removal of duplicates can do anything to the ordering.  You shouldn't depend on the ordering with a `union all`, because nothing in SQL mandates that rows from the first subquery are returned before rows from the second (although in practice this is true).

As a note:  the error you are getting is caused by the first `order by`, not the second.